# Display and Modify CSS variable ? (Module)

Tags: theming

I'm developing a basic module that allows site admin to have the [NavBar](https://www.drupal.org/project/navbar) for mobile and [Administration menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_menu) for the desktop view.

This can easily be done by adding this CSS.

```
#navbar-administration {
    display: none;
} 


@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 959px) {

    #navbar-administration {
        display: block;
    }  /* show it on small screens */;
}

#admin-menu {
    display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {

    #admin-menu {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

I'm using [hook_page_build()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_build/7) to display it on every page. Now I want user to be able to change on an administration page the `960` width which is the default line break to changes menu to their desired value.

My question  how can I display  the default variable value (`960`) on a text field and it can be modify the css once the number on the text field is been change.

Comment: I have seen similar set ups whereby the module recreates the css file after saving a change, then the css file is loaded as normal per page request

Comment: Core color module does this. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!color!color.module/function/color_scheme_form_submit/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many options:

- Make a system settings form that stores the value to a drupal variable. Read that value from your (themes) css. Then when that form is submitted in your theme form submit handler have code clears the cache:   `cache_clear_all("{$theme}:css:*", NULL, TRUE);`. Where `$theme` is your theme name. The CSS should be re-generated on page load.
- I believe the [LESS module](https://www.drupal.org/project/less) allows you to easily make CSS variables applied to your files (in Less-3.x or greater for drupal). If you're not currently using LESS, then this is less helpful (pun NOT intended!)

Answer (score -1):

If you make the menu 100% wide inside the div and use jquery resize by dragging it should auto adjust the menu when dragged.

[example of div resizing when dragged](http://jsfiddle.net/YZX6B/11/)